# Fourth Brâhmana - what is the Sanskrit word for "seized"?

Tags: sanskrit, brihadaranyaka-upanishad

A translation of a verse in the [Fourth Brâhmana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe15/sbe15061.htm#fn_340) states:

> *Now as the sounds of a drum, when beaten, cannot be seized externally (by themselves), but the sound is seized, when the drum is seized or
>   the beater of the drum; And as the sounds of a conch-shell, when
>   blown, cannot be seized externally (by themselves), but the sound is
>   seized, when the shell is seized or the blower of the shell; 'And as
>   the sounds of a lute, when played, cannot be seized externally (by
>   themselves), but the sound is seized, when the lute is seized or the
>   player of the lute;*

Here, the translation "seized" is used many times.

What is this word "seized" in Sanskrit, readible (transliteration) in English?

Comment: I think the words used there are: 'grahaṇāya', 'grahaṇena', 'gṛhitaḥ' .....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are referring to verses 7-8 of [Adhyaya 2 Brahmana 4](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brihadaranyaka-upanishad/d/doc117950.html) of the Brihadaranyaka Upanishad:

> sa yathā dundubherhanyamānasya na bāhyāñchabdāñchaknuyādgrahaṇāya, dundubhestu grahaṇena—dundubhyāghātasya vā—śabdō gṛhītaḥ || 
>   sa yathā śaṅkhasya dhmāyamānasya na bāhyāñchabdāñchaknuyādgrahaṇāya, śaṅkhasya tu grahaṇena—śaṅkhadhmasya vā—śabdō gṛhītaḥ ||

The word translated as seizing is [grahaṇa](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?tinput=grahaNa&direction=SE&script=HK&link=yes&beginning=).